# Is it possible to modify a field in a Windows Event?

Tags: logging, events, active-directory

I'm trying to create a report that sends information of events 4624 (only Remote Interactive) and the only way to know who tried to logon is with the IP address.

Is it possible to modify that field so I can make an `ipconfig -a IP` and show the hostname + IP in that field. Making a new field for the event is also an interesting option.

I've been trying to format the report, but it takes the information from the event, and it doesn't give the hostname so I have no way of knowing it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The log itself shouldn't allow you to alter the field.  (If it does, please have Microsoft fix that!)

What you can do is when creating your report, copy the information from the log then add information to the copy.

If you were using PowerShell it might be something like this:
$Hostname = Resolve-DnsName 
$EventRecord | Add-Member -NotePropertyName ClientHostname -NotePropertyValue $Hostname